# Icons are invisible in my Intellij plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, path, intellij-plugin

I am creating my own plugin for Intellij.
I am trying to show icon near my own language files and I faced a problem: icon has size 1px * 1px and I can't see it near file's name.

Visualisation of problem
[image]

Here is the code how I found out size of icon.

```java
    public Icon getIcon() {
        System.out.print("GetIcon\n");
        System.out.println(SimpleIcons.FILE.getIconWidth());  // prints 1
        System.out.println(SimpleIcons.FILE.getIconHeight());  // prints 1
        System.out.println(SimpleIcons.FILE);
        return SimpleIcons.FILE;
    }
```

And that is how I load the icon (example from JetBrains tutorial)

```java
package org.intellij.sdk.language;

import com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleIcons {
    public static final Icon FILE = IconLoader.getIcon("/icons/jar-gray.png", SimpleIcons.class);
}
```

All code is reachable, i checked it.

I though file path is wrong but found many examples with same folder "icons".

I also tried other paths (for example absolute) and other icons

Any ideas what i do wrong?

Comment: When you tried to debug the code, did you check for `File#exists()` on the icon file using "Evaluate expression"?

Comment: I checked. You are right, file doesn't exist. Do you know what path should I pass to getIcon? I didn't found "icons" folder at all and absolute path as an argument didn't help too

Comment: Finally, the solution is very simple. Just move jar-gray.png into resources folder!